# restrict app only to tablets

Tags: android

I am using,

```
<supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="false"
        android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

I am more concerned about the android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"

Does my app appear on Nexus 7 tablet?

Comment: Nexus7 has a 1,280 x 800 resolution. It should show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I added the supports-screens tag in the AndroidManifest.xml, I could select Nexus7 in the publisher website and unchecked all the other devices.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to find out is to test it on an actual device or in the Eclipse AVD.

The docs say...

> > in order for a device to be considered compatible with your application, the device's smallestWidth must be equal to or greater than this value. (Usually, the value you supply for this is the "smallest width" that your layout supports, regardless of the screen's current orientation.)
> >
> > For example, a typical handset screen has a smallestWidth of 320dp, **a 7" tablet has a smallestWidth of 600dp**, and a 10" tablet has a smallestWidth of 720dp. These values are generally the smallestWidth because they are the shortest dimension of the screen's available space.

As it states above, the smallestWidth of a 7" tablet is `600dp` so I think your settings should work but the golden rule is to test it, both in the Eclipse Android Virtual Device and in an actual device.

Setup an AVD with `Nexus 7 (7.27", 800 x 1280:tvdpi)` as the device and see how it goes.

Comment: If I setup AVD, I can force load onto it. If I add supportscreens tag, then it won't show up on those devices in the play store.

Comment: True. The specifications for `android:smallScreens` say `An application that does not support small screens will not be available for small screen devices from external services (such as Google Play), because there is little the platform can do to make such an application work on a smaller screen.` But I think you should be fine with a Nexus 7 tablet, still would suggest you to test it on an actual device to be sure.